# PowerBI desktop report different from PowerBI server

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server

I'm trying to update a powerBI report by uploading it on powerBI server after modifing a couple of filters

After having modified it correctly, i am able to upload the file without any error making use of the 'replace' button of the PowerBI server UI

[image]

After that unfortunately it seems that the data isn't filtered correctly as the file shows, because i find some that should not be present in the report at all.

My report has many filters activated and the interested one is an integer filter the should accept only values between 0.00001 and 5 ( in column 'SCR LQ')

[image]

This is what i see in the file

[image]

And this is what i see on the uploaded report

[image]

Can anyone explain what cause this problem and how to fix it?

Does not seem a cache issue to me beacuse if i use the 'Edit in Power BI Desktop' button from the web UI then the problem does not occur and the data is shown correctly, so it seems that the filters are not red the right way...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you use Edit in Power BI Desktop, Make sure you save, In transit, if you loose VPN/internet access your changes will not save.

It is always super safe to use Publish save option or Upload

Comment: thanks for the advice but i do not have the possibility to use the publish option